# Preamp stage for audio amplifier using LM741CN clipping too early

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, homework, preamp, voltage-clipping

I'm trying to build the preamp stage for an audio amplifier circuit using the LM741CN. I'm using a variable resistor for Rf so that I can vary the gain.

What I'm finding is that when I have Rf set to 20k I would expect the gain to be 21 (using A = Rf/Ri + 1), however I'm getting clipping at about 1.2 V no matter what the input voltage is, in this case I'm using 300 mV.

EDIT: This is only the preamp stage for an audio amp circuit the power is later going to be further amplified using a class AB amp so it isn't necessary for me to go have a large gain for this stage. I was just wondering why the its clipping at 1.2V.Im just going to keep using this circuit and keep the gain fairly low as Im going to be amplifying it again later on.

[image: Circuit im simulating (Left hand side op amp is used to make a split rail power supply to provide a constant +-2.25V)]

[image: Oscilloscope reading for above circuit]

Comment: Where is @audioguru for a comment on a 741?

Comment: Try a TL0xx op-amp instead.

Comment: 741 is ancient. You must let it go.

Comment: @rdtsc is a TL0xx likely to work any better than a 741 considering the OP is only using a single 4.5V supply?

Comment: *Anything else* will have better specs than a '741.

Comment: Never, *never* use an LM741 if you have any other options.

Answer (score 3):

The 741 can't get even close to the voltage rails:

[image]
*Source: TI 741 datasheet*

You need another opamp or another voltage source to power your circuit.

> The op-amps im allowed to use are TL074CN,CA3140EZ, LM358AP and the LM741CN

The LM358A is slightly better but none of them have rail-to-rail inputs and outputs:

[image]
[image]
*Source: TI LM358 datasheet*

Since it is just a preamp, maybe this voltage swing is enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really use an LM741 op amp at low voltage, like 4.5V. The output is not rail-to-rail, so at low voltage you will only get a couple volts swing on the output.

Comment: Ive benning looking at the data sheet for it but I cant figure out where it says that in the data sheet. The op-amps im allowed to use are TL074CN,CA3140EZ, LM358AP and the LM741CN. which on would you suggest I use for this circuit

Comment: @hasin You need to download the data sheets for all the opamps you can use. Look for the maximum output voltage swing specification and see which part does the best. Perhaps one will stand out as better than the others. These are all 40+ year old designs that a hobbyist may have gotten from their grandfather's junk box. Modern opamps will do much better.